# Repeated roots of $x^3 + xy + z = 0$ for fixed values $(y,z)$. (Reid, Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 0.1)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Show that for fixed values of $(y,z)$, $x$ is a repeated root of $x^3 + xy + z = 0$ if and only if $x = \frac{-3z}{2y}$ and $4y^3 + 27z^3 = 0$.

I know that the discriminant of this cubic is $-4y^3 - 27z^2$, and thus, our polynomial only has a repeated root iff $4y^3 + 27z^3 = 0$. However, I'm not sure how to approach the other part of the problem.

I suppose one could use the analog of the quadratic formula for cubics, but I was hoping to find a "cleaner" approach or one that is more helpful while continuing through the text.

I would also appreciate any insight of different methods for solving like problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is a repeated root of $x^3 + xy + z $, then $x$ is a root of the derivative $3x^2 + y$. This gives $y=-3x^2$ and so $z=-x^3-xy=2x^3$.